# Is it unprofessional to get a second job after my boss invested money in me?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, conflict, part-time, conflict-of-interest

I finally got my first job in my chosen (and hyper-competitive) field.
For this job, I moved to a small country town and I am one of very few people that do this job in this town.

My new boss invested ~$15k AUD in a certification before I started at this job and that has made me very competitive in the local market.

Unfortunately, the job is only part time, meaning I have time to add a second job to my schedule. Would it be unprofessional to find a second job? I don't want my current boss to think I am trying to screw him out of the investment he made in me.

Comment: did you sign any additional docs to take certification? If your boss doesn't want you any more --Does he feel unprofessional to fire you?

Comment: Is that second job in any way connected to that certificate? There is a difference working for your bosses competitor half the day, versus just having another job to make money.

Comment: Have you asked your boss about picking up extra hours / shifts / days in your current job? That would at least be a good precursor to talking to them about if they’re ok with you taking a second job.

Comment: I would like to get a job in my field if possible. The certification will certainly help get a job in the field.

Answer (score 7):

First thing, check your employment contract. If there's nothing specific that stops you from engaging in a second job, then it comes to your judgement. If you feel, that you can take up a second job, without disturbing the work requirements for the first job (deliverables, availability, maintaining confidentiality etc), then you can take up a second job.

As long as you can fulfil the work requirements in the first job (for which you were trained), there is usually nothing else stopping you from getting another job done.

Answer (score 7):

When the company tied a key function and expense to somebody that is part-time they took a risk. Unless they are paying you enough money to equal full-time pay, they have to realize that once you find a full-time job that will pay you enough you will  leave.

To protect themselves they should have used whatever means they have based on local laws to keep you employed. They may be able to require you to reimburse them for the training class/certification unless you stay a few years. They could limit the types of outside employment you can get.  These rules would have had to have been in place before you started or before you received the training.

Even with these types of protection in place, they have to know once the time expires you can leave any time.

Keeping you part-time just adds to the situations that may cause you to leave.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your current contract does not have a **competition clause**, also known as *[non-compete agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-compete_clause#:%7E:text=In%20contract%20law%2C%20a%20non,party%20(usually%20the%20employer).)*, (you never know) or an **exclusivity clause**.

> On social media, some remote workers brag about working two or even three full-time jobs simultaneously without letting any of their other employers know about the hustle. Such gumption is not illegal, and it is not unethical. But some employers want to prevent it to ensure their employees give them their full attention. To do so, an employer should use an “exclusivity clause” in their employment contracts.
>
> **An *exclusivity clause* is a provision in an employment contract that restricts an employee from working for another employer at the same time.** This means that during the term of employment (and not after), the employee is required to work “exclusively” for their current employer.

Source: [goHeather](https://www.goheather.io/post/all-about-exclusivity-clauses)

If the OP's second part time job is unrelated to his first, there should be nothing to worry about.  But in their shoes I would always tell both my employers that my availability is reduced. For example, a coworker could get sick and either your first or second employer might assume you can cover that person's job while on sick leave. This is a situation that has happened to me several times, and each time I had to explain that I was not free outside my hours of contract. There were exceptions in the past, but if I was called to cover a coworker I knew I was the company's last resort.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything inherently unprofessional about having two part-time jobs.

It might actually benefit your boss in that it allows him to maintain a certain function in his business (with an expensive training requirement), without having to pay a whole full-time wage for the worker (the saving on which will eventually dwarf the cost of training).

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately, the job is only part time, meaning I have time to add a
> second job to my schedule. Would it be unprofessional to find a second
> job? I don't want my current boss to think I am trying to screw him
> out of the investment he made in me.

There's nothing unprofessional about finding a second job when all you have is a part time job.

If your boss has any sense, he will understand. Few bosses could expect you to get by on just part time work.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right to full time employment. If this company doesn’t want to give you full time employment, then two half time jobs is absolutely fine ethically. The boss gets the money he invested anyway, and it’s his choice to find more work for you.